# How to solve “nan loss” in Keras NN, arising with high number of features?

Tags: python-3.x, neural-network, keras, nan, loss-function

I am training a neural network using Keras, but get a nan loss when adding more features. I have tried the following solutions, mentioned in other discussions: lower learning rate, a different optimizer, adding epsilon=1e-08 / clipnorm=1. argument for optimizer. However, this did not solve it.

The dataset is small, with 1000 elements. I use different feature sets. When using 25 features there is no problem and good performance. But when using all 53 features, I get only nan losses. (When using the feature sets separately, there is no problem either so I think the problem is not in the feature sets themselves but in their high number). The network is below. Any suggestions to solve this?

```
embedding_layer = Embedding(nb_words,
                            EMBEDDING_DIM,
                            weights=[embedding_matrix],
                            input_length=300,
                            trainable=False)
lstm_layer = LSTM(75, recurrent_dropout=0.2)

sequence_1_input = Input(shape=(300,), dtype="int32")
embedded_sequences_1 = embedding_layer(sequence_1_input)
x1 = lstm_layer(embedded_sequences_1)

sequence_2_input = Input(shape=(300,), dtype="int32")
embedded_sequences_2 = embedding_layer(sequence_2_input)
y1 = lstm_layer(embedded_sequences_2)

features_input = Input(shape=(f_train.shape[1],), dtype="float32")
features_dense = BatchNormalization()(features_input)
features_dense = Dense(200, activation="relu")(features_dense)
features_dense = Dropout(0.2)(features_dense)

addition = add([x1, y1])
minus_y1 = Lambda(lambda x: -x)(y1)
merged = add([x1, minus_y1])
merged = multiply([merged, merged])
merged = concatenate([merged, addition])
merged = Dropout(0.4)(merged)

merged = concatenate([merged, features_dense])
merged = BatchNormalization()(merged)
merged = GaussianNoise(0.1)(merged)

merged = Dense(150, activation="relu")(merged)
merged = Dropout(0.2)(merged)
merged = BatchNormalization()(merged)

out = Dense(1, activation="sigmoid")(merged)
optimizer = nadam(epsilon=1e-08, lr = 0.00001)
model = Model(inputs=[sequence_1_input, sequence_2_input, features_input], 
  outputs=out) 
model.compile(loss="binary_crossentropy", optimizer=optimizer)
early_stopping = EarlyStopping(monitor="val_loss", patience=5)
best_model_path = "best_model" + str(model_count) + ".h5"
model_checkpoint = ModelCheckpoint(best_model_path, save_best_only=True, 
save_weights_only=True)

hist = model.fit([data_1_train, data_2_train, f_train], labels_train,
                 validation_data=([data_1_val, data_2_val, f_val], labels_val),
                 epochs=15, batch_size=BATCH_SIZE, shuffle=True,
                 callbacks=[early_stopping, model_checkpoint], verbose=1)
```

Comment: Is `labels_train` entirely between 0 and 1?

Comment: Well, 'labels_train' consists only out of 0s and 1s.

Comment: Among the input samples, do you have some that are all zeros? (May be a problem in the batch normalization, division by zero).

Comment: There is a high chance that "relu" is causing the issue (all zeros) before the last normalization.

Comment: As far as I can visually check, there are no inputs observations (rows) among the features which are all 0s. Some features do contain only 0s in the columns though.

Comment: Is there a workaround for the last "relu"?

Comment: You could try just "linear", "sigmoid" or "tanh" for test purposes. If it works, and if you do need "relu", maybe you could create a lambda layer just to sum an epsilon. Maybe moving the gaussian noise forward solves it.

Comment: Instead of "relu", I tried "linear", "sigmoid" or "tanh" in the last layer before the output layer. But still only loss = nan. Moved GaussianNoise to last layer, but still only loss = nan.